# Decrease image size automatically over a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a script but I'm not sure what to look for.

I have a webpage that has the body tag with a background image.

```
body {
background: url(eye.gif)repeat;
background-size:91px 91px;
}
```

What I am hoping to achieve is when the page loads it shows the background image as 991px then slowly decrease by 10px over a set time until the original size of 91px.

I'm not sure if there is away to do this, or even another way that when the page is loaded it is zoomed in and then zooms out automatically over time.

Basically when the page is loaded you will see the image twice and then over time you will see more and more.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: I point you in the direction of the javascript [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function and the jquery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

Comment: Use a timer to change the CSS class, each one with a different dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample using JQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/frUvf/16/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').animate({'background-size':'10000px'}, 50000);
})
```

Comment: your fiddle and answer do not match

Answer (score 3):

if you use background-size your using css3 and so you can use keyframes

no javascript needed.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bganimation{
0%{background-size:991px 991px;}
100%{background-size:91px 91px;}
}

body{
background: url(eye.gif)repeat;
background-size:91px 91px;
-webkit-animation:bganimation 20s linear; // 20s = 20 seconds
}
```

for more support you need to add the other specific prefixes (-moz,-ms..)

Comment: You are correct, i wouldn't mind adding a CSS2 and jQuery edit to this though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript for the animation or could take a look at CSS3 Transformations: http://web.archive.org/web/20180414114433/http://www.pepe-juergens.de/2013/02/css3-transform/

Comment: I'd use jQuery to allow support for older browsers

Comment: Or force the people to use an actual browser ;)

Comment: jquery = lag. especially on mobile devices

Comment: @PKeidel if only it was that easy :)

Comment: Once it is working with jQuery, it is easier to port it.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JS:

```
var lowerBound = 250,
    step = 10,
    duration = 1000,
    image = document.getElementById('image');

(function resizer () {
  if (image.clientWidth > lowerBound) {
    image.style.width = image.clientWidth - step + 'px';
    var timer = setTimeout(resizer, duration);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}());
```

Just change the lowerBound/step/duration variables to whatever you need them to be.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/yE9y5/)

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
var body = $('body');
var zoom = 2;
var interval_zoom = 0.5;
var time_interval = 90000;

  setInterval(function(){
    body.css("zoom", zoom);
    zoom = zoom - interval_zoom;
    if(zoom<=1)
      clearTimeout(this);


  }, time_interval )
```

Zoom and interval must be calculated